# Windows Fortran compiler for legacy Finite Element (1980) code?

Tags: finite-element, fortran

The version of Fortran used comes from  Montreal Ecole Polytechnique in 1980. I need a compiler for Fortran for Windows 7 or Windows 8.

Comment: It depends on whether or not the code contains non standard elements but in principle every modern Fortran compiler can still compile old Fortran code. So best guess is to have a look the non commercial gfortran or the commercial Fortran compiler from Intel (ifort)

Comment: Do modern open source or well-known commercial packages not compile it (like GNU Fortran or Intel Fortran, respectively)? Both should work on Windows. Does it not work on Linux/UNIX OSes? Which Finite Element program? (should've pressed Enter before I went to make lunch!)

Comment: As a separate question, why would you want to deal with 40-year old programs other than for software archeology?

Comment: You can use the Intel Fortran compiler for Windows to compile your code. Of course, you may have to slightly modify parts of it, if it contains non-portable Fortran extensions.